The user, group or application 'appid=XYZ' does not have secrets get permission on key vault
I am trying to create vaults and give get permission to developers.
I am a devops and want to manage this vaults only by me.
Terraform validate command doesn't give any error. But apply is failed like.
│ Error: checking for presence of existing Secret "ConnectionStrings--DBContext" (Key Vault "https://deneme-beta.vault.azure.net/"): keyvault.BaseClient#GetSecret: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="The user, group or application 'appid=04b071-811ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46;oid=b78911-511d7b-4968-a654-4389ef10196d;numgroups=1;iss=https://sts.windows.net/d07101-51110d-4151-abf2-d14d0729ada3/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'deneme-beta;location=germanywestcentral'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287" InnerError={"code":"AccessDenied"}
│ 
│   with azurerm_key_vault_secret.vault_secrets["deneme-beta-ConnectionStrings--DBContext"],
│   on main.tf line 59, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "vault_secrets":
│   59: resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "vault_secrets" {

I have 3 tf files as;
My locals.tf file is;
locals {
  contexts = [
    {
      "name" : "deneme-beta",
      "vars" : [
        {
          "variable" : "ConnectionStrings--DBContext",
          "value" : "data source=192.168.10.1:1521/beta;password=deneme-test;user id=PRJ"
        },
        {
          "variable" : "MinioSettings--SecretKey",
          "value" : "flkjdwfkljdkfjdjkfjdkfjkdjf"
        },
        {
          "variable" : "RabbitMQConfiguration--Password",
          "value" : "94j9j9j9j"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "deneme-stage",
      "vars" : [
        {
          "variable" : "ConnectionStrings--DBContext",
          "value" : "data source=192.168.10.1:1521/stage;password=deneme-stage;user id=PRJ"
        },
        {
          "variable" : "MinioSettings--SecretKey",
          "value" : "dkmkdemmdcmdkmckmdkcmddcdcdcdc"
        },
        {
          "variable" : "RabbitMQConfiguration--Password",
          "value" : "223232323"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  variables = merge([for context in local.contexts : {
    for vars in context.vars :
    "${context.name}-${vars.variable}" => {
      name     = context.name
      variable = vars.variable
      value    = vars.value
    }
  }]...)

}

My provider.tf file is;
terraform {
  required_version = ">=1.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~>2.48"
    }
  }

}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

My main.tf file is;
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "rg_vault_deneme"
  location = "germanywestcentral"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "ygm_vaults" {
  for_each                   = toset([for context in local.contexts : context.name])
  name                       = each.key
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                   = "standard"
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7
  purge_protection_enabled   = false

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "ygm_vault_access_policy-devops" {
  for_each     = azurerm_key_vault.ygm_vaults
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.ygm_vaults[each.value.name].id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  key_permissions = [
    "Get", "List", "Update", "Create", "Import", "Delete", "Recover", "Backup", "Restore",
  ]

  secret_permissions = [
    "Get", "List", "Set", "Delete", "Recover", "Backup", "Restore",
  ]

}

data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

data "azuread_user" "developer" {
  user_principal_name = "deneme@live.com"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "ygm_vault_access_policy-developer" {
  for_each     = azurerm_key_vault.ygm_vaults
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.ygm_vaults[each.value.name].id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azuread_user.developer.object_id

  key_permissions = [
    "Get",
    "List"
  ]

  secret_permissions = [
    "Get",
    "List"
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "vault_secrets" {
  for_each     = local.variables
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.ygm_vaults[each.value.name].id

  name  = each.value.variable
  value = each.value.value
}

What is the problem in my config files?
Search google and can't find a good answer.

Thanks for your quick answer.
Your help didn't solve my problem but gives the idea of the root problem.
You said that; developers must have Set and Delete permissions not to get the error. But I want only the owner (devops) have a permission to manage vault. I want developers permissions not exceed Get and List grants.
By the help of your answer I understandt that terraform also the owner ability to create this resources. But there is a problem in the order. The grant access permissons and vault secret check are done asyncronous. So without the access permission the other part secret creation is giving error.
I added a depends on to secret creation. By the help of this dependency terraform create a syncronous operation without giving any error.
My last part main.tf is changed to;
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "vault_secrets" {
  for_each     = local.variables
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.ygm_vaults[each.value.name].id

  name  = each.value.variable
  value = each.value.value
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.ygm_vault_access_policy-devops
  ]
}

And in the destroy process terraform gives purge permisson is not found. I also added "Purge" permission to my grant list.
  key_permissions = [
    "Get", "List", "Update", "Create", "Import", "Delete", "Recover", "Backup", "Restore", "Purge"
  ]

  secret_permissions = [
    "Get", "List", "Set", "Delete", "Recover", "Backup", "Restore", "Purge"
  ]

Thanks for your help. By the help of your answer I was able to focus more on the problem.

Hello @Serkan2 You only mentioned the creation part in the query. If the deletion of the resource was also included, I would have definitely shared the list of permissions needed to resolve all your issues. I hope my solution addresses the issue you mentioned in the query for creation of resource part.
